# Iframe worldPay integration in website asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iframe, worldpay

Currently we are with a major problem with iframe-worldpay integration.

I'm currently using worldpay template form, if the template form is placed in my website the form is visible however when I load the worldpay template form inside an iframe the worldpay template form visibility set to hidden.

Worldly doesn't provide a solution for this scenario, is there any work around?

**EDIT**

Sample Code

```
   <script src="https://xx.xxxx/xx/worldpay.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function WorldPay() {
                /*WorldPay-START*/
                Worldpay.setClientKey('<%=WorldPayClientKey%>');//<YOUR_CLIENT_KEY>
                Worldpay.reusable = false;
                Worldpay.templateSaveButton = false;
                Worldpay.useTemplate('aspnetForm', 'paymentDetails', 'inline', function (obj) {
               //Form Submission here
                });
                /*WorldPay-END*/
            }
        </script>


<div id="paymentDetails"></div> //WORLDPAY iframe loads here
```

`If this page is not inside an iframe world pay loads else it does not`

Comment: Can you please post a sample HTML of your code would be easier to investigate.
But on a quick note I be more careful using payment gateway with iFrames

Comment: have updated the question with sample code mate...

Comment: Please read this,i hope this would help you
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38736509/2772563